# creating a guide along the page edges in Scribus

Tags: scribus

I want to create a box on a page that spans the width of the page. In order to do that, I want to draw a rectangle and move the corners so that they snap to the edges of the page. I have turned on the snap to grid and snap to guide options.

[image: page border in scribus]

I am unable to create a snap guide on the edge of the page, it is visible until it is about .80 points away from the right edge and any closer than that to the edge, it disappears.

I want to create some default guides in this Scribus document, similar to what the second part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20195684/1484229 suggests.

Is there a "guides around page" option or something like it in Scribus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Guides manager in Scribus to define horizontal and vertical guides at arbitrary positions.

The dialogue is available under the main menu `Page -> Manage Guides...`

Entering "0.000" is not allowed but if you use "0.0001" it will accept your input and display it as "0.000" anyway. This level of accuracy is never going to be respected in output.

You can apply the same philosophy and set your page margins to 0 `Page -> Manage Page Properties...`

Alternatively, you can specify the exact size and position of your rectangle in the properties dialogue. As you're looking for a rectangle to span the page, simply enter the page width into the width field for the rectangle and you've saved a whole load of messing with guides.  To ensure it goes from edge to edge either set the x value to 0 or use the align dialogue and define page as the align target.

You will find that although you can define positions with ridiculously high levels of accuracy they often get "adjusted" slightly.  This is almost never a problem in real life output.